# how to display a rect inside a list

Tags: python, list, pygame, rect

What i am trying to do is create a list in which i would append a number of rects and then draw them latter using their index. However this appears to not be working for some reason the shape(rect) is not displayed in the app window so i would appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction or give me another method of doing this.

thanks in advance.

```
def buffer(self):

    self.blocks = [] # rect container


    """
    ---- creating and appending rects ----

    """

    for x in range(5):
        self.blocks.append(

            pygame.draw.rect(
                self.screen,
                (255,255,0),
                [0,0,50,50]
                )

            )

    while 1:

        self.key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return 0


        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

        self.blocks[0] # draw rect

        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(self.fps)


    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
    quit()
```

Comment: 'not working' is a rather vague description? What does it do? What errors do you get or what do you see instead of the expected?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html) code. It explain very well how to make a list of 'things'. Basically you want to make a class and then instantiate it into a list. Therefore, making a list that contains several copies of the same class. Then just iterate through the list to draw, update, move etc. through each class instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create at least tuples with color, x, y, width, height

```
self.blocks = [] # rect container

# creating and appending rects

for x in range(5):
    self.blocks.append( ((255,255,0),[0,0,50,50]) )
```

Then you can use it to draw rect

```
# draw rect
color, (x, y, w, h) = self.blocks[0] 
pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h))
```

`pygame.draw.rect` creates rect on the screen but doesn't create object which you can keep on list.

Comment: your missing a closing parenthesis on the for loop. Other than that it worked thanks